# How to create a rectangular box over the region containing red to white color in this pseudo-color image in matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, location, detection, bounding-box

I have a Pseudo-color mapped image containing values from 0 to 3 that are assinged colors from blue, green, red, yellow and white. I want to create a rectangular box that will automatically be set only on the regions containing the colors from red to white. It should point out that this is the region containing colors from red to yellow.

Comment: Upload the original image to any image hosting site and put a link here.. also another image with red box manually drawn over the image to show your expected output.

Comment: be more specific ... the color is float I hope you have range `<0,3>` and 5 distinct colors. What do you mean by `I want to create a rectangular box that will automatically be set only on the regions containing the colors from red to white` ... you want to find that area or recolor colors there according to what rule ... add as much relevant info as you can because right now is all just guess work